# HTTP scraper for Python Package

Tags: python, web-scraping, https

I'm trying to make my first [Python package](https://github.com/josh-bone/sportsrefscraper/blob/main/sportsrefscraper/utils.py) as a learning experience. There's a lot of things that I suspect I am doing poorly, but this post is specifically about my HttpRequest class. I made this class so that I can use retries and persistent session.

```
class HttpRequest:
    __session = None

    @staticmethod
    def __init__session__():
        if HttpRequest.__session is not None:
            return
        stderr.write("Initializing HTTPS Session\n")
        HttpRequest.__session = HttpSession()
        retries = Retry(total=3,
                        backoff_factor=1,
                        status_forcelist=[],  # 429
                        allowed_methods=False)
        HttpRequest.__session.mount("https://", HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))

    @staticmethod
    def get(url):
        print(f"Querying {url}")
        HttpRequest.__init__session__()
        return HttpRequest.__session.get(url)
```

I use this class basically everywhere in the package, so I want to make sure I'm doing this well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to be pretty happy with `requests` defaults,
but I imagine you need specific retry behavior,
so I won't comment on that.

---

```
    __session = None
```

That's just weird.
Please don't do that -- name mangling is seldom helpful.
Prefer a single leading `_` underscore to mark it private.

---

Rather than naming it `_init_session`
(a perfectly nice and helpful name),
you might prefer `_get_session`.
I'm just looking at how it's used, is all.
Currently it is invoked for Singleton side effects,
and caller must carefully *remember* to call it.

When designing an API we strive for more than
just clear names. We also want it to be easy to use,
and hard to accidentally misuse.
So a getter feels more natural, in this case.

---

```
        if HttpRequest.__session is not None:
```

Feel free to abbreviate that to just:

```
        if HttpRequest.__session:
```

---

```
    @staticmethod
    def get(url):
        print(f"Querying {url}")
        HttpRequest.__init__session__()
        return HttpRequest.__session.get(url)
```

Both methods are declared static,
yet they immediately dive into class attributes.
Doesn't seem like a good match.
Prefer:

```
    @classmethod
    def get(cls, url):
        ...
        cls._init_session()
        return cls._session.get(url)
        #
        # or maybe just:
        # return cls._get_session().get(url)
```

Also, instead of `print`, consider using a
[logger](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html).
That way callers can dial verbosity up and down as they wish.
Plus the logged timestamps can come in very handy
when diagnosing why an overnight run suddenly slowed down.

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I was looking for. I meant to specifically ask about the use of class vs. static methods and persistent session, but you addressed both topics anyway!

Comment: Oh, my! I didn't even notice this one: `stderr.write("Initializing HTTPS Session\n")`. Definitely a logger would be more friendly, so I don't have to remember to redirect file descriptor 2. Much better that we `grep` some favorite message out of a combined log stream.

Comment: These print messages may be removed in the future, but according to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html) it seems like print() is better than logging for such messages.

Comment: Certainly `print()` has its place. If you remember to include timestamps / elapsed times in your crawl messages then sure, go for it. My specific objection to `stderr` is it just seems inconvenient to the caller. E.g. if I make this a cron job I get an email unless I `2>&1` or maybe `2> err.log`. The item being logged isn't an error, it is totally routine and expected. But whatever, I'm sure it works for your use case, hang onto it if you like it. Me, personally? I find value in logging "prefix1: %s" and "prefix2: %s" and then grep'ing out a certain prefix during an investigation.